# How to check an ID of a object that has been touched (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

In my View I have an array with a bunch of different points, then I run that array through a loop to create a bunch of different squares in the view. You can also see that I tried using the accessibility identifier to create an ID like system. That's probably a really bad practice but I ran out of ideas haha. Here's the view:

```
#import "LevelOneView.h"


@implementation LevelOneView
@synthesize squareLocations;




- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    squareLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CGPoint dotOne = CGPointMake(1, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotOne]];

    CGPoint dotTwo = CGPointMake(23, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotTwo]];

    CGPoint dotThree = CGPointMake(45, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotThree]];

    CGPoint dotFour = CGPointMake(67, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotFour]];

    CGPoint dotFive = CGPointMake(89, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotFive]];

    CGPoint dotSix = CGPointMake(111, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotSix]];

    CGPoint dotSeven = CGPointMake(133, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotSeven]];

    CGPoint dotEight = CGPointMake(155, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotEight]];

    CGPoint dotNine = CGPointMake(177, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotNine]];

    CGPoint dotTen = CGPointMake(199, 25);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotTen]];

    int numby = [squareLocations count];

    for (int i = 0; i < numby; i++)
    {
        NSValue *pointLocation = [squareLocations objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint tmpPoint = [pointLocation CGPointValue];

        UIImage *theSquare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"square.png"];

        NSString *myID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        [theSquare setAccessibilityLabel:myID];
        [theSquare drawInRect:CGRectMake(tmpPoint.x, tmpPoint.y, theSquare.size.width, theSquare.size.height)];

    }

}


@end
```

So, my goal is to be able to tell which square has been slid over when it is slid over! So I'm looking for an ID like system, that I can check the current slid over object's "ID" and decide what to do with it from there. I tried to write something like that in the view's controller:

```
#import "LevelOneController.h"

@interface LevelOneController ()

@end

@implementation LevelOneController
@synthesize whereStuffActuallyHappens;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"View loaded");
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {

        if ([touch.accessibilityLabel isEqual: @"1"] && CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation))
        {

            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }

    }

}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Once again you can see me trying to use the accessibility label in this case...haha. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Is there a way I could give each individual square an ID, then check that square's ID when it is slid over? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UIImageView` for putting the image on screen instead of `drawRect:` and use the `tag` of that image view for identifying which view it is.

The `tag` property is available for all UIView and its subclasses. (UIButton, UIImageView etc)

From your approach I think there won't be multiple view's when you draw `UIImage` inside the `drawRect:` . All the images will be drawn into one single view. So in addition to you not able to identify an image, when you do a remove from superview,it won't work as expected. Using a `UIImageView` would solve a lot of problems, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh is definitely right with his comments, use `UIImageView` if you can.

Also `touchesMoved` will not detect your squares because you haven't added them as subviews, they are only images drawn in your view, which is another reason you should rather use uiimageviews.

If you are insisting on doing it this (much harder) way: I suggest you to keep an NSDictionary with your ids as keys and cgrect frames of your squares as objects. And then with every touch iterate through all possible keys and call `CGRectContainsPoint` on your objects. Return the affiliated id (key) when point is contained within the rect. But I don't recommend doing so.

Comment: I decided to go with making all of them UIButtons instead of UIImageViews. I though that would be easier? But now my problem: how do I detect when the buttons are slid over?